# Netbean 8 with Bitbucket "clone" issue

Tags: java, git, bitbucket, netbeans-8

I am trying to clone a repository using inbuilt Netbeans git plugin, but it is giving me error "Cannot connect to repository"

So far I've tried:

1. Added bitbucket.org entry into host file.
2. Checked the firewall used to connect internet for netbeans (images attached)

> Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to clone it from command line?

Comment: No, but I think it is because a .git is not the end of the url as for testing purpose I've created another test repo and I am able to clone it thru netbean 8 so I belive this repository is somehow created incorrectly. However thanks for the reply..

Comment: The .git it is the end of url. Your URL should be <https://pdubey@bitbucket.org/efrenolguin/polo_project.git> at least is that way I use to connect my projects from Bitbucket in my Netbeans 8.2.